# Why do I receive the Error: Tensor is disposed, when using tf.grad() to implement FGSM?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow.js, pre-trained-model

I'm trying to implement the Fast Gradient Sign Method (FGSM) on MobileNet with tensorflow.js, however I'm having problems on the latest version (1.0.1) when computing the gradient using tf.grad().

The code is working fine with tfjs version 0.13.0 and below, however updating to any of the later versions results in the following error:

```
core.js:15723 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Tensor is disposed. Error: Tensor is disposed.
at e.throwIfDisposed (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at e.greaterEqual (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at Object.$x (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at n (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at backpropagateGradients (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at tf-core.esm.js:17
at tf-core.esm.js:17
at e.scopedRun (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at e.tidy (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at e.gradients (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
at zone.js:896
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17289)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:502)
at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:487)
at timer (zone.js:2281)
```

The error occurs when calling `tf.grad(lossFunction)`:

Any help/insight is appreciated!

Full code:

```
let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('canvas')

let img = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas, 3) //let img = tf.fromPixels(canvas, 3)
let img4 = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas, 4) //let img4 = tf.fromPixels(canvas, 4)

let model = mobilenet.load().then(model =>
{
    var output = model.classify(img, 3).then(predictions =>
    {
        let tbuffer = tf.buffer([1000])
        var labelClasses = IMAGENET_CLASSES 

        let targetClass = predictions[0].className
        Object.keys(labelClasses).forEach(function(key) 
        {
            if (labelClasses[key].valueOf() == targetClass.valueOf()) 
            {
                tbuffer.set(1, parseInt(key));
            }
        })          

        const oneHotLabels = tbuffer.toTensor()

        const getModelLogits = x => model.infer(x)
        const lossFunction = x => tf.losses.softmaxCrossEntropy(oneHotLabels, getModelLogits(x).as1D())
        const gradientFunction = tf.grad(lossFunction)
        var gradient = gradientFunction(img)


        // scale the gradient and apply to original image
        var perturbation = this.scaleGradient(gradient, 50)
        const zeroes = new Uint8Array(224*224).fill(0)
        let alphaChannel = tf.tensor3d(zeroes, [224, 224, 1]) 
        let perturbationWithAlpha = tf.concat([perturbation, alphaChannel], 2)  
        var adversarialImage = tf.add(tf.cast(img4,'float32'), perturbationWithAlpha)

        // Draw adversarial image to canvas
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d")
        let imgArray = Uint8ClampedArray.from(adversarialImage.dataSync());
        let imgData = context.createImageData(this.imgHeight, this.imgWidth);
        imgData.data.set(imgArray);
        context.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);            

    }) 
})
```

Full repo available here: https://github.com/BenMcFadyen/tfjsFGSM
https://github.com/BenMcFadyen/tfjsFGSM/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

FGSM code originally from: https://github.com/jaxball/advis.js

[full trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l3XK.png)

[successful execution on tensorflow/tfjs@0.13.0, tensorflow-models/mobilenet@0.2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwSko.png)

Comment: 0.13.0 is pretty old; if you'd like to try some intermediate versions (e.g. 0.13.5, 0.14.2, 0.15.1) that could help narrow down when and why the problem arose.  But also: the relevant mechanism for retaining Tensors needed for backprop has just been substantially refactored (https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core/pull/1604) so it would be informative to see what happens when tfjs 1.0.2 is released (or you can build it from head today to find out).

Comment: (never mind that comment; the answer below supplants it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the error and verified manually that https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core/pull/1604 fixes it. The fix will be out in the next TF.js release (`1.0.2`), which we plan to get out by end of this week.

The gradients are working even though MobileNet is now a `tf.GraphModel` instead of `tf.LayersModel`, because the library is eager and can compute gradients on-the-fly.

Answer (score 2):

tensorflow-models/mobilenet@0.2.2 was a `tf.LayersModel`, which provides gradients and thus is retrainable.  However tensorflow-models/mobilenet@1.0.0 was changed to be a `tf.GraphModel` in https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/pull/161, in order to provide MobileNet V2 from TF-Hub.  GraphModels do not provide gradients, and thus your code no longer works.

I think you have several possible paths forward:

1. Stick with working versions if they serve your needs (tensorflow-models/mobilenet@0.2.2 should work with tfjs up to 0.15.3, though that will produce deprecation warnings).
2. Fork tensorflow/tfjs-models at PR #156 and build the mobilenet package there. 
   That's the same as 0.2.2, except that it can be used with tfjs >1.0.0.
3. Fork tensorflow/tfjs-models from head, and revert the model-loading part to use `tf.loadLayersModel()` with the BASE_PATH that was removed in #161.  (This gets you V1 only).
4. Obtain a MobileNet V2 in Keras .h5 format (e.g., from [here](https://github.com/JonathanCMitchell/mobilenet_v2_keras/releases)) and use the [TF.js converter](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/conversion) to get a `tf.LayersModel`.

Comment: Appreciate the help/insight! It seems tfjs@1.0.2 should solve the issue